# How to get outlook user UPN(User Principle Name) for Outlook Office-js based add-in

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

Is there any way to get the logged in user's UPN from Outlook using Office.js?

I tried [`getUserIdentityTokenAsync`](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/1.6/Office.context.mailbox) and`getCallbackTokenAsync` but neither of these gives any relevant information. The closest I can get is the email address using the [`userProfile`](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/1.6/Office.context.mailbox.userProfile) method.

Comment: Can you clarify or give an example of the format that you are looking for? With Office JS you can get the display name and email address of the user using userProfile.displayName and userProfile.emailAddress.

Comment: In a normal setting the UPN and email address are same but for some tenants who are migrated from On Premise AD it could be different its not a recommended practice but still people have it. Please see the following link. https://www.morgantechspace.com/2018/03/userprincipalname-vs-e-mail-address.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not supported by Office.js. There are currently no plans to enable that support.